# Issue in old Joomla template and fix by github

Tags: templates, joomla, modal-dialog, privacy-policy

I don't know if this is the correct location, I've found an issue on my old template and found that has been solved in Github, can anybody point me where to read how to solve it ?

https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/issues/23199

Thank you

I found the issue and read the Github contributors and authors, but didn't understand how to fix it